# How can I get the properties of a Gurobi's Presolve model?

Tags: gurobi, integer-programming, quadratic-programming

I have an integer programming problem with linear objective function and some quadratic constraints. When I use Gurobi to solve this problem, Gurobi uses Presolve to create a Quadratically Constrained Integer Programming model. Now, I would like to know if the objective function of the Presolve model is quadratic too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, you might want to post this question on the operations research site instead, https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do a presolve and then call printStats or write out the lp file.

Answer (score 0):

Gurobi will give you the presolved model with the method [presolve](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_presolve.html) on the model object.  That object is a regular model object and you can query its [attributes](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/attributes.html).  The attribute `isQCP` is true if there are any quadratic constraints.  The attribute `isQP` indicates that the model has a quadratic objective, but no quadratic constraints.  The attribute `NumQConstrs` is a count of the number of quadratic constraints.
You can also use the `printStats` method to print the numbers or you could use the `write` method to write the presolved model to a file.

```
presolved_model = model.presolve()
print(presolved_model.IsQCP)
print(presolved_model.IsQP)
presolved_model.printStats()
presolved_model.write("presolved.lp")
```